# Late bound resolution using COM objet for Excel

Tags: vb.net, ssis

The following is inside an SSIS script task using VB.net

I have read a bit into this error, and it seems that something is wrong with this line:
    worksheet = CType(workbook.Sheets(4), Excel.Worksheet)

My code is below. I think it will be simple for the more experienced folks here.

[image: My code w/ error]

text:

```
Public Sub Main()
       Dim excel As New Excel.Application
        Dim filename As String = "S:\UK\Clients\Direct\xxxxxxx.xls"

    excel.Visible = True
    excel.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename, , False) 'True = ReadOnly

    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    worksheet = CType(workbook.Sheets(4), Excel.Worksheet)


    worksheet.Rows(1).delete()








    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `Option Strict Off` at the top of your code, This will allow late binding.

To know Early vs. Late Binding , refer  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1(v=vs.80).aspx)

you can replace this statement

```
worksheet.Rows(1).delete()
```

with

```
Dim rw As Excel.Range
rw = CType(worksheet.Rows(1), Excel.Range)
rw.Delete()
```

> And set Option Strict On at the top

All your code will be early bound. Hope this helps

Comment: This seems to have worked wonders. Took quite a while for an answer to come through for once. Will this have any negative impact on my code?

Comment: impact will be on performance compartively and early binding prefered over late binding for many reason.  refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1(v=vs.80).aspx